# {% include '' with %} in Django template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use the code below in a specific way.

```
{% include 'your_template_here' with keyword='your_value_here' %}
```

What I wanna do is pass my argument `store_list` into `your_value_here` as an argument for the paramater `keyword`. That is, it should be like the following:

```
{% include 'your_template_here' with keyword={{ store_list }} %}
```

But, it has a syntax error. Is it not allowed to pass a queryset in {% include ' ' with=' ' %} ?

Comment: try `{% include 'your_template_here' with keyword=store_list %}`

Comment: Either drop the {{}} around store_list or try passing it an index, like store_list.0

Comment: @RafaelC When you include {{ }} inside a {% %}, doesn't it throw a remainder error or something like that?

Comment: @RafaelC `keyword=store_list` is perfectly working well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to drop the double-curly braces from your keyword.

```
{% include 'your_template_here' with keyword=store_list %}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would like to pass an array

```
{% include '/blocks/block-products-carousel.html' with
        groups= [
            {title: 'All', active: true},
            {title: 'Power Tools', active: false},
            {title: 'Hand Tools', active: false},
            {title: 'Plumbing', active: false},
        ],
```

Comment: I doubt you tested this code…